# Pidgin still notifies me when buddies come online, even though I'm set to "Do not Disturb"

Tags: ubuntu, notifications, pidgin

Even when I have my status set as "Do No Disturb" Pidgin will still notify me when my buddies come online. It's very disturbing.

I'd like no notifications to pop up while in DND mode. I've checked [the FAQ](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin) and didn't find it.

Can anyone solve this?

This is on Ubuntu, with Pidgin 2.5.5.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As already pointed out, *Do Not Disturb* does not turn off notifications. If you want to do that, go to *Tools > Plug-ins* (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> keypress) and uncheck the '**Libnotify Popups**' plugin that is responsible for the notifications. Enable the plugin when you want to re-enable notifications again.

You can also choose to configure the conditions on which the plugin provides popup notifications. One of the conditions is "Only when available". Check if selecting this will stop notifications when you set your state to anything other than Available.

Comment: Configure Plugin had the option "When buddy signs in" which is ticked by default and quite easily unticked. You are winner :)
Thanks Champ.

Comment: Yep Do not disturb is only a status, not a mode. Its like good old Away on AIM, its just tells buddies you may not be available, with a stronger wording.

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding what the "Do Not Disturb" mode is.

It is meant to inform your contacts that you don't want to be disturbed (by talking to you). It is not to hide all Pidgin alerts and notifications from you.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. Funny, I thought that's how MSN behaved... could be wrong...

Comment: It's also the behaviour in Skype